# seqedplot using TraMineR: how to plot selected hazard curve in one single graph?

Tags: r, traminer

I'm using TraMineRextras and in particular I'm interested in the `seqedplot` function.

Here there is an example:

```
data(actcal.tse)
actacl.tse <- actcal.tse[1:500,]
iseq <- unique(actcal.tse$id)
nseq <- length(iseq)
data(actcal)
actcal <- actcal[rownames(actcal) %in% iseq,]
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(actcal.tse)
seqelength(actcal.seqe) <- rep(12, nseq)
```

Instead of plotting all curves by doing:

```
seqedplot(actcal.seqe, type="hazard", breaks=6, group=actcal$sex, lwd=3)
```

I would only plot the selected curves according to the variable `sex` by using the `ignore` option:

```
seqedplot(actcal.seqe, type="survival", group=actcal$sex, lwd=3, ignore= c("NoActivity", "Start", "FullTime", "Stop", "LowPartTime", "Increase", "Decrease"))
```

How can I plot the Male and Female selected curves in one single graph instead of in two separate graphs?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to bind the sex onto the event type:

```
actcal.tse$event <- sprintf("%s-%s", actcal.tse$event, actcal$sex[match(actcal.tse$id, rownames(actcal))])
```

as there doesn't appear to be an option to use the `groups` parameter to split within a graph.  So try something along these lines, and omit the groups option entirely

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try along the line you suggest.

Comment: This is a good idea. However, without adjusting the population at risk for each sex, the resulting survival probabilities would be wrong. So I am afraid you need to forget about using `seqedplot` for superposing curves by sex.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, I will update the post as soon as I find another solution